# Change between multiple Layouts in AlertDialog

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

basically I want to show a Dialog (AlertDialog for simplicity), I inflate a customTitle view and a custom view.

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
adb.setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_title), null);
adb.setView(R.layout.dialog_first_layout);
adb.show();
```

Now when I click a Button inside this Dialog, I want to replace the Content of the Dialog, and not the whole Dialog. I thought about just calling

```
adb.setView(R.layout.dialog_second_layout);
adb.show(); // or adb.create();
```

but this does not work.

By the way, I also thought about a fragmentmanager inside the dialog, but I don't know if it is the right way.

I apreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: What does _it does not work_ mean?

Comment: Really? But actually it works

Comment: When I do this, it alway shows a Dialog above the primary created Dialog. Instead I want to replace the Layout inside the first Dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, and let me know if you have any problem

```
final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
adb.setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_title), null);
adb.setView(R.layout.dialog_first_layout);
Dialog dialog = adb.show();
dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_second_layout);
    }
});
```

---

Edit:
Ok, since i don't think there is any ways to reserve the custom title that you set to AlertDialog.Builder with the behavior you want, you can do this instead

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final Dialog dialog = adb.create();
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_first_layout_with_title);
dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_second_layout_with_title);
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

The basic idea is you set the content view of the dialog directly(include title and content)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that shows like expected a Dialog above the original Dialog. I really just want to replace the "contentView"

Comment: Oh i know what you expect now :). I will revise my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but unfortunately the titleView disapears and cannot be reset to the dialog.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I did yesterday. I have a question: qhy do you get a Dialog, instead of a AlertDialog from adb.create() or adb.show()? If I set it to the AlertDialog I have at least the methods of AlertDialog, although they don't work ..

Comment: Also I am using a custom View for the title which I need a reference for. There are some animations that would need a big workaround to display as desired when instantiating the title over and over again. Since I have too less reputation I can't even upvote your post, but I am glad you helped me!

Comment: @FelixPK Actually you get an instance of AlertDialog there. Dialog is the parent of AlertDialog, so you can use Dialog too. It is a concept of polymorphism in Java. You can accept it as answer if it solved your problem.